# How to get enum custom value?

Tags: c#, enums

I have an `enum` like this:

```
public enum ProductGroup
{
    A = 1,
    B = 2,
    C = 4,
    D = 8
}
```

How can I get ProductGroup enum values? For example, when my enum value is ProductGroup.C I want get its value 4;

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just cast it as an `int` to get the index value.

So:

```
ProductGroup productGroup = ProductGroup.C;

Int32 productGroupIndex = (Int32)productGroup;
```

In the above example, `productGroupIndex == 4`.

Comment: just for the info there is no need of extra temporary variable here ........you can do it directly

Comment: "when my enum value is..." - from this, I made the assumption that it was an instance of the ProductGroup enum that would need the casting.

Answer (score 8):

Just cast the enum

```
int val = (int)ProductGroup.A;
```

Answer (score 5):

```
 ProductGroup pg = ProductGroup.C;
 Console.Write((int)pg);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert/cast the enum:

```
int productGroup = Convert.ToInt32(ProductGroup.C);
```

**or**

```
int productGroup = (int)ProductGroup.C;
```